# ValidationError: User validation failed: username_email: Path `username_email` is required. using express validator, next.js, express and mogoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, express-validator

I am trying to search mongodb to see if a email exists using [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html#example-checking-if-e-mail-is-in-use) before I save it.

This is the excerpt of my route:

```
.post(body('username').custom(value => {
        return UserModel.findOne({ 'username_email': value }).then(user => {
            if (user) {
                return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
            }
        });
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ValidationError: User validation failed: username_email: Path `username_email` is required.
    at new ValidationError (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:30:11)
    at model.Document.invalidate (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2292:32)
    at p.doValidate.skipSchemaValidators (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2141:17)
    at /Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1037:9
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
POST /users/registration 500 29.796 ms - 51
```

This is my complete route:

```
var router = require('express').Router()
var UserModel = require('../models/UserModel')
var { body } = require('express-validator');

router
    .route('/registration')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        // req.session.visits = req.session.visits ? req.session.visits + 1 : 1
        UserModel.find({}, (err, users) => {
            if (err) res.status(500).send(err)
            res.json(users)
        })
    })
    .post(body('username').custom(value => {
        return UserModel.findOne({ 'username_email': value }).then(user => {
            if (user) {
                return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
            }
        });
    }), async(req, res, next) => {

        try {
            let newUser = new UserModel(req.body)

            let savedUser = await newUser.save()

            if (savedUser) return res.redirect('/users/registration?success=true');
            return next(new Error('Failed to save user for unknown reasons'))

        } catch (err) {
            return next(err)
        }
    })



module.exports = router
```

And this is my Schema/Model:

```
/* eslint-disable no-var */
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var emailValidator = require('email-validator')
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt') // hashing function dedicated for passwords

const SALT_ROUNDS = 12

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username_email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        index: { unique: true },
        validate: {
            validator: emailValidator.validate,
            message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid email address`
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        index: { unique: true },
        minlength: 8
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

UserSchema.pre('save', async function preSave(next) {
    var user = this
    var hash
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next()
    try {
        hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, SALT_ROUNDS)
        user.password = hash
        return next()
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err)
    }
})

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function comparePassword(candidate) {
    return bcrypt.compare(candidate, this.password)
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

And for good measure here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Transition, Button, Form, Grid, Header, Message, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      fadeUp: 'fade up',
      isLoggedIn: true,
      duration: 500,
      isVisible: false,
      username: '',
      password: '',
      usernameError: false,
      passwordError: false,
      formError: true,
      formSuccess: false
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this)
    this.handleIsLoggedInClick = this.handleIsLoggedInClick.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    var { name, value } = event.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  }

  handleIsLoggedInClick() {
    this.state.isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn ? this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true }) : this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false })
  }

  handleBlur() {
    var { username, password, usernameError, passwordError } = this.state

    var mailFormat = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
    var error = false

    if ((!username.match(mailFormat)) && (!usernameError)) {
      this.setState({ usernameError: true })
      error = true
    } else {
      this.setState({ usernameError: false })
    }
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    var { username, password } = this.state

    var mailFormat = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
    var error = false

    if (!username.match(mailFormat)) {
      this.setState({ usernameError: true })
      error = true
    } else {
      this.setState({ usernameError: false })
    }

    if (password.length <= 8) {
      this.setState({ passwordError: true })
      error = true
    } else {
      this.setState({ passwordError: false })
    }

    console.log(`error ${error}`)
    if (error == false) {
      this.setState({ formError: false, formSuccess: true })
    }

    window.fetch('http://localhost:8016/users/registration', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email: username, password: password })
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(`response ${response}`)
      return response.json()
    }).then(function (data) {
      console.log('User created:', data)
    })
  }

  render() {
    var { username, password, usernameError, passwordError, formError, formSuccess, isLoggedIn } = this.state
    return (<div className='login-form' > {
      /*
                      Heads up! The styles below are necessary for the correct render of this example.
                      You can do same with CSS, the main idea is that all the elements up to the `Grid`
                      below must have a height of 100%.
                    */
    } <style > {`body > div, body > div > div, body > div > div > div.login-form { height: 100%;}`} </style>

      <Grid textAlign='center' style={{ height: '100%' }} verticalAlign='middle'>
        <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 450 }}>
          <Header as='h2' color='teal' textAlign='center' > {isLoggedIn ? `Register for an account` : ` Log-in to your account`}</Header>

          <Form size='large' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} error={(formError || formSuccess) || usernameError || passwordError} success={!formError && !formSuccess}>
            <Segment stacked >
              <Form.Input fluid icon='user'
                iconPosition='left'
                placeholder='E-mail address, e.g. joe@schmoe.com'
                name='username'
                value={username}
                onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                error={usernameError}
              />

              <Transition visible={usernameError} animation='scale' duration={500}>
                <Message error content='Email is in incorrect format e.g. joe@schmoe.com' />
              </Transition>

              <Form.Input fluid icon='lock'
                iconPosition='left'
                placeholder='Password'
                name='password'
                value={password}

                onChange={this.handleChange}
                error={passwordError}
              />

              <Transition visible={passwordError} animation='scale' duration={500} >
                <Message error content='Paswword needs to be greater than eight characters.' />
              </Transition>

              <Button color='teal' fluid size='large' disabled={!this.state.username || !this.state.password} > {isLoggedIn ? `Register` : `Log-in`} </Button>

              <Transition visible={(!formError && formSuccess)} animation='scale' duration={500} >
                <Message success header='Your user registration was successful' content='You may now log-in with the username you have chosen' />
              </Transition>

            </Segment>
          </Form>

          {
            !isLoggedIn
              ? <Message >
                New to us ?
              <a onClick={this.handleIsLoggedInClick}
                  href='#' > Register! </a> </Message> : <Message >
                <a onClick={this.handleIsLoggedInClick}
                  href='#' > Back to Login </a> </Message>
          } </Grid.Column> </Grid> </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Register
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a typo in your code. When you make a request to your backend you are attaching the following body:

```
body: JSON.stringify({ email: username, password: password })
```

Which has `email` parameter. And then, inside your validator, you're trying to validate `username` prop.

```
.post(body('username').custom(value => {
```

And `username` is undefined there.

So, you have to follow a single naming convention and it should work.